# Разделение бинарного представления числа на группы разной длины и обратное преобразование их в числа

Tags: c#, парсер

Имеется число (ushort)26903, в бинарном виде оно выглядит следующим образом: 110100100010111,
как разделить бинарный код данного числа на следующие последовательности:
11010 0100 010111 после чего перевести обратно в 10-ю систему счисления, любого из целочисленных типов данных?

Comment: Вот, например, выделение средней части: `(n & (0xf << 6)) >> 6`

Comment: И по какому принципу это должно происходить?

Comment: Исходя из предыдущего комментария, возможно выделять куски нужного размера справа налево, к примеру вот так:
из "11010 0100 010111"
выделить сначала 7 бит справа, потом следующие 4 бита и потом остаток

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно почему они поделены на группы 5-4-6

Comment: Это ответ от устройства, суть в следующем, мы получили ответ в виде целого числа типа (ushort), в карте памяти к устройству, описывается каким образом нужно распарсить данные, и там написано следующее:
0-6 биты - год, 7-10 биты месяц, 11-15 биты день, принцип по которому вычисляется эта дата мне понятна, но вот как перенести в код вообще не понимаю.

Comment: Так проще: `(n >> 6)  & 0xf`

Comment: Это да, ваш пример выделяет центральную часть и хорошо отрабатывает, я правда не понимаю пока что как оно работает, есть ли возможно делать к примеру следующие действия: 
110100100010111 - исходное значение, после сдвига на 7 вправо у нас отбрасывается вот эта часть 0010111, могу ли я отбросить ту часть, которая не совпадает с выделенной частью после сдвига вправо?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ushort n = 0b0110100100010111; // 26903

int x = 0b0000000001111111;
int y = 0b0000011110000000;
int z = 0b1111100000000000;

int a = (n & x);
int b = (n & y) >> 7;
int c = (n & z) >> 11;

Console.WriteLine($"{a,-5} {Convert.ToString(a, 2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{b,-5} {Convert.ToString(b, 2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{c,-5} {Convert.ToString(c, 2)}");
```

`n` - это ваше число.
`x`, `y`, `z` - маски. Я думаю, хорошо видно, какая часть числа будет выделяться по этим маскам.
`a`, `b`, `c` - результат.

Получается дата 23 год, 2 месяц, 13 день.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я кажется понял принцип по которому это все работает! Пример очень наглядный!